# How to preset value of <h:inputText> with a GET parameter? The f:param in h:inputText does not seem to work

Tags: jsf, http-get, http-request-parameters

I have a GET form on which I need to preset the value of an `<h:inputText>` to a request parameter.

I tried using `<f:param>` inside `<h:inputText>`.

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="get" action="search.xhtml">
    Search
    <h:inputText name="txtKeyword" type="text" id="txtKeyword" placeholder="Enter keyword">
        <f:param name="keyword" value="#{param['keyword']}"></f:param>
    </h:inputText>
</form>
```

And I tried to access it as below.

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
String keyword = request.getParameter("keyword");
// keyword is null.
```

However, it returned `null`. What's the correct approach?

Comment: Hi Balus, I was able to accomplish this with a JSP form with the sql commands within the form (no controller - MVC, of which I am trying to correct)

the page is named:  index.jsp

Comment: Yes, I would like to pass the value of the input field - I tried <input> but it also does not pass the value.

Comment: I can see why you asked the question... Balus...

You can't achieve it using <h:inputText>. Its name is autogenerated by JSF based on the client ID (which is in turn based on component ID and all of its naming container parents).

and

there is no attribute called name in h:inputText,

Comment: @Balus

SOLVED>>>
'
<form name="frmSearch" method="get" action="search.xhtml">
 
   Search

    <input name="keyword" value="#{param['keyword']}"/>

    <f:param name="keyword" value="#{param['keyword']}"/>     

</form> 
'